# Unable to transpose an array using .T

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

This should work but the dimension of c and new_c is always the same. c is an array of dim (13,1) and c_new is also an array of (13,1)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
n = np.arange(1, 26, 2, dtype=float)
c = 4 / (np.pi * n)
new_c = c.T
```

Comment: The transpose of a matrix of size `(N,)` is `(N,)` since there is only one dimension.

Comment: The shape of `c` is not (13,1). It is (13,) which is a difference.

Answer (score 3):

n is of shape (13,) which is different from (13,1). (n,) means that it only has a single dimension, which means that there are no dimensions that transpose can swap. If you do

```py
n = np.arange(1, 26, 2, dtype=float).reshape(-1,1)
```

you get what you wanted to have.
There are also other ways of achieving this like

```py
n = np.arange(1, 26, 2, dtype=float)[:,None]
```

or

```py
n = np.expand_dims(np.arange(1, 26, 2, dtype=float), axis=1)
```

Comment: Could have also used `expand_dims`